# How can I display the insert mode prompt on the left when using zsh with the in vi-mode plugin?

Tags: vim, prompt, oh-my-zsh

I am using zsh with command-line editing using [vi-mode](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/vi-mode) and it displays the right hand prompt as `<<<` when in vi's `INSERT` mode.

Is there a way to display or add it to the right prompt? The `vi-mode` script is quite short so I have copied it here in its entirety.

```zsh
# Updates editor information when the keymap changes.
function zle-keymap-select() {
  zle reset-prompt
  zle -R
}

# Ensure that the prompt is redrawn when the terminal size changes.
TRAPWINCH() {
  zle &&  zle -R
}

zle -N zle-keymap-select
zle -N edit-command-line


bindkey -v

# allow v to edit the command line (standard behaviour)
autoload -Uz edit-command-line
bindkey -M vicmd 'v' edit-command-line

# allow ctrl-p, ctrl-n for navigate history (standard behaviour)
bindkey '^P' up-history
bindkey '^N' down-history

# allow ctrl-h, ctrl-w, ctrl-? for char and word deletion (standard behaviour)
bindkey '^?' backward-delete-char
bindkey '^h' backward-delete-char
bindkey '^w' backward-kill-word

# allow ctrl-r to perform backward search in history
bindkey '^r' history-incremental-search-backward

# allow ctrl-a and ctrl-e to move to beginning/end of line
bindkey '^a' beginning-of-line
bindkey '^e' end-of-line

# if mode indicator wasn't setup by theme, define default
if [[ "$MODE_INDICATOR" == "" ]]; then
  MODE_INDICATOR="%{$fg_bold[red]%}<%{$fg[red]%}<<%{$reset_color%}"
fi

function vi_mode_prompt_info() {
  echo "${${KEYMAP/vicmd/$MODE_INDICATOR}/(main|viins)/}"
}

# define right prompt, if it wasn't defined by a theme
if [[ "$RPS1" == "" && "$RPROMPT" == "" ]]; then
  RPS1='$(vi_mode_prompt_info)'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

try these config below in your `.zshrc` file:

```
oldPS1="$PS1"

function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {

    VIM_NORMAL_PROMPT="%{$fg_bold[yellow]%} [% NOR]%  %{$reset_color%}"
    VIM_INSERT_PROMPT="%{$fg_bold[green]%} [% INS]%  %{$reset_color%}"
    PS1="${${KEYMAP/vicmd/$VIM_NORMAL_PROMPT}/(main|viins)/$VIM_INSERT_PROMPT}$oldPS1"
    PS2=$PS1
    RPS1=""
    RPS2=""
    zle reset-prompt
}

zle -N zle-line-init

zle -N zle-keymap-select
```